# Untick the "view updates" box directly from code

Tags: netlogo

Is there anyway to untick the "view updates" box directly from code. I am using RNetLogo from R and that's why wish to accomplish it code directly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually unchecking the box is impossible except from Java using the controlling or the extensions API. You might request it as a feature from the RNetLogo authors; they could add it using the controlling API.

For your purposes though, I suspect you'd probably do fine just with the `no-display` and `display` commands instead. See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#no-display